# Cannot open Excel (.xlsx) files with Apache POI on Android

Tags: java, android, excel, kotlin

When I used "Intent" class to open and read an excel file (.xlsx) from another file app on Android, I got this error message.
After I got the url about the file from the file app, I gave that inputstream to WorkbookFactory.
When my class tried to execute this process,
"WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)", I got an error with an exception thrown such as SAXNotRecognizedException or POIXMLException.

```
D/test: uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/0C19-391B%3Atest.xlsx

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myexceloperatesample, PID: 20662
    org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:657)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:88)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:339)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:314)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:232)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:198)
        at com.example.myexceloperatesample.utility.ExcelDataProcessor.getWorkbook(ExcelDataProcessor.kt:67)
        at com.example.myexceloperatesample.utility.ExcelDataProcessor.execute(ExcelDataProcessor.kt:36)
        at com.example.myexceloperatesample.list.ListCheckFragment.startForResult$lambda-0(ListCheckFragment.kt:45)
        at com.example.myexceloperatesample.list.ListCheckFragment.$r8$lambda$mjTpkbLSgZW3CDTcSV4joyxwpyA(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.myexceloperatesample.list.ListCheckFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:4)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1.onStateChanged(ActivityResultRegistry.java:148)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:271)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:313)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:151)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3058)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:587)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:279)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2791)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3062)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:587)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:279)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2791)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:486)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)
            ... 52 more
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3389)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$XmlReaderSaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3076)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.getSaxLoader(Locale.java:3061)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source:6)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86)
            ... 56 more
     Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.setProperty(ExpatReader.java:170)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3383)
            ... 63 more
```

And Here is my codes. the reason for the "if" statement is that the ".xls" format can be read without causing the errors.

```
class ExcelDataProcessor(
    private val activity: FragmentActivity,
    private val result: ActivityResult,
    private val excelViewModel: ExcelViewModel
) {
    fun execute() {
        val uri = result.data!!.data
        val workbook: Workbook = getWorkbook(uri!!)
    }

    private fun getWorkbook(uri: Uri): Workbook{
        return if (uri.toString().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            Log.d("test", "uri: $uri")
            val inputStream = activity.contentResolver?.openInputStream(uri)
            WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)

        } else {
            val inputStream = activity.contentResolver?.openInputStream(uri)
            WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ListCheckFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding : FragmentListCheckBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val excelViewModel: ExcelViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
            result: ActivityResult? ->
        if (result?.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ExcelDataProcessor(requireActivity(), result, excelViewModel)
                .execute()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentListCheckBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

        binding.fileImportButton.setOnClickListener { openFileProvider() }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun openFileProvider() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "*/*"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,
                arrayOf(
                "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                )
            )
        }
        startForResult.launch(intent, null)
    }
}
```

And here is my dependencies. Various dependencies are included, as we have tried the latest version of Apache POI, a slightly older version, and responded to different errors.

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myexceloperatesample"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'

    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.1"
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.1"
    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.0.2'
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:1.4"
    implementation 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.2.2'
    implementation files('libs/javax.xml.stream-3.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/dom4j-2.0.3.jar')
    kapt 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.2'
```

Comment: `When I used "Intent" class to open...` What do you mean? There is no intent in your code and you try to open an inputstream for an unknown url.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you. I've edited my question and added another class's code.

Comment: Why did you? It explains nothing. And an 'Intent' class cannot open and read a file to begin with. So you might explain what you really do.

Comment: @blackapps Perhaps I wasn't able to use the expression 'used "Intent" class' well.
I use the method, openFileProvider(), to open a file app, let the user select an Excel file, and let my app receive the result of the selection.
Then I tried to process the received result by having the ExcelDataProcessor class instantiated in registerForActivityResult().

Comment: You are summing up your own functions which tells us nothing. As far as i can see now you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select a file. Then in onActivityResult you obtain an uri for which you are going to open an input stream. After that you offer that inputstream to WorkbookFactory. That is what you do. And that you should have written at the first lines of your post.

Comment: According to the docs, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXNotRecognizedException.html  that exception is thrown when the XML has invalid property identifiers.  This means either the XML is invalid, or you're not configuring the parser right.  Neither of which we can help with given the code you've posted.

Comment: You can also look at the stack trace and see that it's throwing in setProperty.  Which validates that it's having a problem parsing a property in your document.

Comment: Thank you very much. What other code is needed to solve this problem? I can provide it immediately if it is the xml description in the xlsx file used for testing.

Comment: You might try creating a quick desktop JVM app to open your document with POI, to rule out the possibility that the file itself is the problem.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you. I have trying creating the desktop JVM app to open and manipulate a xlsx file on my desktop, not on Android. Then I was able to run it without generating any errors. So I think there is no problem with my xlsx file.